# How can I configure clipboard as Windows?

Tags: desktop-environments, clipboard

Windows 7, XP... maintains the copy text if you close the application.

How could I configure Ubuntu for this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It **is** the default behaviour in Ubuntu - do you have any issues?

Comment: @Takkat: Yes, I had, I lost the clipboard a few times in the past.

Comment: I found this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence as you said @DKBose :) Please, could you reply as an answer and I'll set your reply as the solution? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence), whether the clipboard contents are remembered after the source application is closed depends on the application but several programs in X11-based operating systems do not ensure that the clipboard is remembered.

The user may want to install a clipboard manager to deal with this issue. Some common ones available from the software center are Parcellite, Clipit, xfce4-clipman, and Klipper. A longer list is available [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/clipboard#List_of_clipboard_managers).